# XSS found in the United Airlines website

Tags: xss, javascript

An XSS bug was found in United Airlines by Strukt and Burelogic [(full article here)](https://strukt93.blogspot.in/2016/07/united-to-xss-united.html?showComment=1511087015341#c9207984505572454865). Apparently they were using this to protect from XSS:

> Basically, the code overrides the native `alert()`, `confirm()`, `prompt()`, `unescape()`, and `document.write()`functions and nullifies them, so calling them does absolutely nothing. This was implemented as an "XSS protection".

I was wondering if using a base tag to point to a js file with a simple XSS payload would be blocked by the same function that blocked the XSS in the first place.

Comment: You can't import JS with base, you would need `script`. Or are you suggesting that you should set base href to a domain that you control, and then host the code without the XSS protections there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSP will block your JS from a third party website. However, in the event that you manage to find a CSP bypass, XSSObject.proxy will override those functions anyway, because a javascript src runs on the page it is called.